# Count how many dates fall into the between interval

Tags: sql, count, firebird, between

I am trying to write an SQL which calculates the "performance date" for our company.

To get a feeling I write an extract from the SQL:

```
..CASE
     WHEN EXTRACT(weekday FROM deliverydate) = 1 THEN (bek.deliverydate-3)
     WHEN EXTRACT(weekday FROM deliverydate) = 2 THEN (bek.deliverydate-3)
    ELSE
    bek.deliverydate-2 
    END AS performancedate
```

This works quite well. (Weekend moves the performance day by one extra day, because the delivery needs one more extra day)

What I tried next, was to implement "public holidays" by which the "performancedate" is moved by one more day per public holiday-day.

My English is not that good, so I hope you understand this far.

I got all the public holidays into form:

```
'01.01.2020'
'10.04.2020'
'13.04.2020'
'01.05.2020'
'21.05.2020'
'01.06.2020'
'11.06.2020'
'03.10.2020'
'01.11.2020'
'25.12.2020'
'26.12.2020'
'01.01.2021'
'02.04.2021'
'05.04.2021'
'01.05.2021'
'13.05.2021'
'24.05.2021'
'03.06.2021'
'03.10.2021'
'01.11.2021'
'25.12.2021'
'26.12.2021'
'01.01.2022'
'15.04.2022'
'18.04.2022'
'01.05.2022'
'26.05.2022'
'06.06.2022'
'16.06.2022'
'03.10.2022'
'01.11.2022'
'25.12.2022'
'26.12.2022'
```

for the next ~2 years.

Now I want that when a holiday, falls between the "deliverydate" and the "performance date" the **new** performancedate (new variable for example, it doesn't need to be the same variable) is moved by one more day by each holiday which falls into the period.

I hope there is solution like

`..when '18.07.2020' between performancedate and deliverydate then '1' else '0'"`

and then it's possible to use `Sum(newvariable)` in combination with `group by` and add it to the former performance date.
This just as a possible solution.

(PS: I am very limited in the functions of the SQL program, because its just a SQL Menue in the our merchandise management. `select` etc. works...)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very hard to follow.  Based on the title:

> Count how many dates fall into the between interval

If you want the number of public holidays between two dates, then one option is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*)
        from holidays h
        where h.holiday_date >= t.performance_date and
              h.holiday_date <= t.delivery_date
       ) as num_holidays_between
from t;
```

I suspect, though, that you want to calculate a date at some point in the future taking holidays into account.  If that is the case, I would suggest that you ask a *new* question, provide sample data, desired results, and try for a clearer explanation of what you want to accomplish.